# Interpreting log-linear model for contingency table in R

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, contingency-tables, log-linear

I'm looking at sample data and trying to *determine whether there is any association between the height of the husband and that of the wife* below. I don't fully understand what the symbolic representation of the model is basically - the example below is an extract from the textbook. The full code for the model in **R** is provided below - T,M,S stand for "Tall", "Medium", "Short" respectively.

In particular, given the coefficients in the summary below, what is the formula relating count ~ husband + wife? I know that the model here is (the linear predictor is):

$\mu + \alpha_j + \beta_k$

where j={S,M,T} and k = {S,M,T} but I don't fully understand how this is then used

```
count <- c(18, 28, 14, 20, 51, 28, 12, 25, 9)
w <- rep(c("T", "M", "S"), 3)
h <- c(rep("T", 3), rep("M", 3), rep("S", 3))
wife <- factor(w)
husband <- factor(h)
height <- data.frame(count, husband, wife)
```

The data looks like:

```
> height
  count husband wife
1    18       T    T
2    28       T    M
3    14       T    S
4    20       M    T
5    51       M    M
6    28       M    S
7    12       S    T
8    25       S    M
9     9       S    S
```

Now fit a model:

```
height.glm <- glm(count ~ husband + wife, family = poisson)
summary(height.glm)
```

The summary is:

```
all:
glm(formula = count ~ husband + wife, family = poisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
     1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9  
 0.849  -0.448  -0.242  -0.870   0.109   0.664   0.230   0.340  -0.751  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    3.917      0.122   32.15  < 2e-16 ***
husbandS      -0.766      0.178   -4.30  1.7e-05 ***
husbandT      -0.501      0.164   -3.06   0.0022 ** 
wifeS         -0.713      0.171   -4.17  3.1e-05 ***
wifeT         -0.732      0.172   -4.26  2.1e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 50.5890  on 8  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  2.9232  on 4  degrees of freedom
AIC: 56.57

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Comment: One possibility is to measure the difference in height as a single value, rather than the two individual heights.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks - this is a good tip but it doesn't answer the question above. The problem is fully solved, I just need pointers on interpreting the R results in terms of the analytical model

Comment: Without interaction term, you cannot tell anything about the association between the two height variables.